# How can I remove "Real name" from my PGP key?

Tags: pgp

I use GnuPG and, as it was mentioned in this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9403/how-can-i-remove-my-personal-data-from-my-pgp-public-key/9467#9467), the mail address can be left out of a user ID when edited through the command line interface.

Is there any way - even if it means using a manual hack, a third-party tool or anything else - to remove/skip filling the "Real name" field?

Comment: Do you want to remove the name from an existing key or create a new one without it? Technically, this is no problem at all: The PGP key format contains just a **UID** field which is not required to abide by any particular format (such as the usual "Real Name <email@address.tld>").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenPGP user IDs as defined in [OpenPGP 4880, OpenPGP, 5.11.  User ID Packet (Tag 13)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.11) are formed by arbitrary strings, "Real Name (Comment) mail@example.org" is not more than a convention. Following the specifications, it even may be the empty string.

> #### 5.11.  User ID Packet (Tag 13)
>
> A User ID packet consists of UTF-8 text that is intended to represent
> the name and email address of the key holder.  By convention, it
> includes an RFC 2822 [RFC2822] mail name-addr, but there are no
> restrictions on its content.  The packet length in the header
> specifies the length of the User ID.

GnuPG (at least in version 2.1, which I used to verify this statement) does not enforce a name, either -- just omit any content. In fact, GnuPG actually seems to support empty-string user IDs!

```
gpg> adduid
Real name: 
Email address: mail@example.org
Comment: 
You selected this USER-ID:
    "mail@example.org"

Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit?
```

Not all versions of GnuPG allow free-form user IDs by default and require `--allow-freeform-uid`. From `man gpg`:

> **`--allow-freeform-uid`**
>
> Disable all checks on the form of the user ID while generating a new one. This option should only be used in very special environments as it does not ensure  the  de-facto
> standard format of user IDs.

Comment: Thank you. This indeed works in 2.1, my problem was that I was using GnuPG 2.0.35. That version (and I suspect most versions before) don't let the user pass without entering a minimum of 5 characters.

(GUIs like GPA or Kleopatra don't allow skipping these, regardless of GnuPG version.)

To tie in to @yyyyyyy's comment: I couldn't create a key with such a fully emtpy uid, but I could add it to a key which already had a uid and then delete the old one (`deluid`).

Comment: You're right, I can verify this at least using GnuPG 1.4 and did not find a way around this. I guess using GnuPG 2.1 should work out as a solution in most cases.

Comment: @SutarbiDudek: Have a look at `--allow-freeform-uid` which allowed non-, also listed in GnuPG's manpage. I added some notes in the answer.